# Limits with Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I have been studying linear algebra for a while now and i recently came across a very interesting notion,the limit of a matrix.It's seems very interesting but i can't really find lectures on this matter(i'm still in high school).Can anyone recommend some good materials?Thank you very much!

Comment: Just use Google Scholar and type "limit of a matrix".

Comment: Not sure about this very general thing you ask about as a starting point. But for example, perhaps you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential (it has nice relations to differential equations, to relating trace and determinant, and will give some experience with taking limits of matrices) and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can say that
$$
\lim_{x\to a} \left[ \begin{array}{cc} p(x) & q(x) \\ r(x) & s(x) \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \lim_{x\to a} p(x) & \lim_{x\to a} q(x) \\ \lim_{x\to a} r(x) & \lim_{x\to a} s(x) \end{array} \right]
$$
so that the expression on the left is the limit of a matrix-valued function of $x,$ and one would say that that is the limit as $x\to a$ of the matrix that appears to the right of the expression $\text{“} \lim\limits_{x\to a}. \text{''}$

This appears in a number of contexts. the exponential function
$$
\exp A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}
$$
where $A$ is a matrix, occurs in the study of differential equations. And the sum is the limit of the sequence of finite partial sums.

Something like a limit of a matrix is involved in the matrix of infinitesimal generators used in the study of continuous-time Markov chains.

Comment: Thank you very much!